# Libreoffice is eating all cpu

Tags: libreoffice, strace

On my debian box, LibreOffice (even while idle) is eating 100% of the CPU is runs on.

I used strace and those 4 lines are constantly displayed as in a loop (as such I can tell which one comes first):

```
recvmsg(14, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}], 2, 546) = 1 ([{fd=9, revents=POLLIN}])
read(9, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
write(9, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
```

I have to confess I don't know how to exploit this.

Is there any way to know at which ressources the fd #9 corresponds?

This appeared after a huge update of the distribution so that it is not easy to guess which specific update could have triggered this. The Debian bug tracker did not seem to contains related bug reports.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check `ls -l /proc/$LibreOfficePid/fd/9` to see which resource fd 9 is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have read strace man page more carefully since the explanation can be found there : one just need to add the *-y* and *-yy* options to get full information about file descriptors.

For those more interested in the LibreOffice tag than in the strace one, this led me to this [(closed) Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=887404). Now I just need to wait LibreOffice 6.0 migrates to buster before to reinstall libreoffice-gtk[23].